# Makecert still what to use to self sign?

Tags: ssl, azure, makecert

I don't have makecert anywhere on my system despite having 3 Vstudio editions and several SDK's.  Can someone please tell me where I can find a copy or how else I should generate a certificate to test SSL in azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [SelfCert](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/02/13/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net/) tool! Very handy and works perfectly. All my self-signed certificates are generated with this tool.